# nested form, embedded docs, mongoid 2.2.0 problem

Tags: mongoid, nested-forms

I cant seem to find answer for this here or with the google, any help would be awesome.
The Building saves correctly, but the embedded doc PriorityArea doesnt get updated...
I want to eventually have it ajax a new form for new priority areas evenutally, but need it to update first.

### Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind in BuildingsController#update

#### Calling Document#find with nil is invalid

```
class Building
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :priority_areas
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :priority_areas, :allow_destroy => true, :autosave => true
end

class PriorityArea
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :building, :inverse_of => :priority_areas
end
```

`#view`

```
= form_for [@customer, @building] do |f|
  ...
  ...
  = f.fields_for :priority_areas do |pa|
    = f.name
    ...
    ...
```

`#controller`

```
@building.update_attributes(params[:building])
```

It correctly yeilds the correct data from the db, but fails to error above on building#update. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

update
in the building#update im
puts params[:building][:priority_areas_attributes].to_yaml

which yeilds

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
"0": !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
name: area 51
location: near front door
notes: ""
priority: "1"
id: ""
"1": !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
name: area 52
location: near rear door
notes: ""
priority: "2"
id: ""
```

im guessing the problem is the null id:""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the null id
it needed to have an ObjectId to work correctly. stupid error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact problem.  `simple_form` was automatically passing an id parameter to my controller, but it was blank.

Why was the id for my embedded document blank?  I'm guessing it's because I imported the parent document via mongoimport.  If I manually generate a parent document via web forms, then the embedded documents have IDs as expected.

Here was my workaround:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars

  ####
  # simple_form_for / embedded document workaround
  #
  # Because simple_form wants to provide the ID for an existing object, 
  # it will output a blank ID because imported embedded documents
  # have an ID of nil.
  #
  # Intercept it to avoid 
  #   Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind in FoosController#update

  def bars_attributes=(attribs)
    attribs.each do |key, value|
      index = key.to_i
      fixed_attrib = value.delete_if { |k,v| k=="id" and v=="" }
      self.bars[index].update_attributes(fixed_attrib)
    end
  end


end

class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :foo
end
```